Type <Null> is not a subtype of Map<String, dynamic>
I'm trying to login into my app using supabase and flutter, but it keeps getting the error Type  is not a subtype of Map<String, dynamic> and I have no clue how to fix it. The application uses UserModel which is an extension of User, User would most probably be used for auth and UserInfo is used for other features.
Here's my code
UserModel
class UserModel extends User {
  final UserInfoModel userInfo;
  final String email;
  final String username;
  final int totalPosts;
  final int follower_count;
  final int following_count;

  UserModel({
    this.totalPosts = 0,
    this.follower_count = 0,
    this.following_count = 0,
    required this.email,
    required this.username,
    required this.userInfo,
  }) : super(
          email: email,
          username: username,
          userInfo: userInfo,
        );

factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      userInfo: UserInfoModel.fromJson(json['userInfo']),
      totalPosts: json['totalPosts'],
      email: json['follower_count'],
      following_count: json['following_count'],
      username: json['username'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'userInfo': userInfo.toJson(),
      'totalPosts': totalPosts,
      'follower_count': follower_count,
      'following_count': following_count,
    };
  }

and the login method
@override
  Future<UserModel> logInWithEmailPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final response = await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithPassword(
        password: password,
        email: email,
      );
      if (response.user == null) {
        throw const ServerException('User is null!');
      }
      final userData = await supabaseClient
          .from('users')
          .select()
          .eq('uid', response.user!.id);
      return UserModel.fromJson(userData.first);
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      throw ServerException(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      throw ServerException(e.toString());
    }
  }


Looks like your userData is empty.

The error message means that a function expecting a specific data format (Map<String, dynamic>) received a null value, likely in the UserModel.fromJson method.
The issue arises in the logInWithEmailPassword method at the line where userData.first is expected to be a Map<String, dynamic>, but it's likely null. This could be because the select query isn't returning any results, making userData.first null. To resolve, ensure userData.data isn't null and has at least one element before accessing userData.first.
@override
Future<UserModel> logInWithEmailPassword({
required String email,
required String password,
}) async {
try {
  final response = await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithPassword(
   password: password,
   email: email,
 );
 if (response.user == null) {
   throw const ServerException('User is null!');
  }
  final userData = await supabaseClient
     .from('users')
     .select()
     .eq('uid', response.user!.id);
   if (userData.data != null && userData.data!.isNotEmpty) {
   return UserModel.fromJson(userData.data![0]);
  } else {
   throw ServerException('No user data found for this user.');
 }
} on AuthException catch (e) {
 throw ServerException(e.message);
 } catch (e) {
  throw ServerException(e.toString());
  }
 }

You can use the above function and check if your problem is resolved.

Aora for some reason it say The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'
